# Passing Parameters to a Stored Procedure from Intergration Services Package

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Is it possible to pass the parameters of a stored procedure, when the stored procedure is being executed from an Integration Service Package. Ideally I would like the value of a variable defined inside a SSIS package to be passed as parameter to the stored procedure. Is it possible, if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're calling this from an Execute SQL Task. If so, use the Parameter Mapping section to choose the variable and the parameter name.

Comment: You can pass parameters to the SSIS package as well which in tern can be passed to SP.